# Only one message box is popped up after validating the 2 validations

Tags: c#, validation

```
abstract class User
{
    public string Username;
    public string Password;

    public virtual bool Validate(string username, string password)
    {
        Username = "";
        Password = "";
        if (password == Password && username == Username)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect password or username");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

form code:

```
 private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      UserAdmin admin = new UserAdmin();
      UserEmployee empp = new UserEmployee();
      bool validateAdmin =  admin.Validate(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
      bool validateEmpp  = empp.Validate(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);

      if (validateAdmin==true || validateEmpp == true )
      {
          this.Hide();
          // Create a new instance of the options class
          Options opt = new Options();
          opt.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
          // Show the settings form
          opt.Show();
      }
```

When the first validation is false it keeps checking the second validation as well.By doing so 2 message boxes are being popped up.

EDIT:
Can you show only one message box instead of 2? it only shows the message box if the username or password is incorrect

Comment: if you want check both validation is true, but if the first one is false break your script. You must use the "&&" instead "||"

Comment: @DanielMelo i dont want that both validation are true, i just want one either validateAdmin or validateEmpp

Comment: You need to put the MessageBox in the click function instead of the User function.  You are calling the User function twice so you will get two instances of the MessageBox.

Comment: @jdweng The thing is i want to override the message if the username and password are correct ex: if admin logs in the message should say "logged in as admin" or when employee is logged in it says "Employee logged in" and so on.

Comment: The problem is when both admin and empp both fail.  The way the code is organized you will always get two MessageBox errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine validations in *conditional expression*:

```
if(admin.Validate(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text) && empp.Validate(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
{
    ... // is ok
}
else
{
    ... // when either Validate from left to right is not ok
}
```

This way if `admin.Validate` return `false`, then `empp` is not validated.

Comment: What i meant is that I want the two validation checked but only one pop up message.

Comment: Sometimes validation is expensive (e.g. database lookup), then just keep in mind what you don't need to validate `empp` at all if `admin` validation prior has failed. Otherwise my answer is perfectly valid, though I should mention your mistake (you are using `||` instead of `&&`).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the standard way to stop execution of the code - is throwing an exception. So what You could do - is throw a 'ValidationExceptio' and implement appropriate ex handlers

Answer (score 0):

To stop showing two message boxes, Remove the message box from method and include it into the click event. So the method will be like this:

```
public virtual bool Validate(string username, string password)
    {
        if (password == Password && username == Username)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And the click event will be like :

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserAdmin admin = new UserAdmin();
        UserEmployee empp = new UserEmployee();
        bool validateAdmin = admin.Validate(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        bool validateEmpp = empp.Validate(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        if (validateAdmin)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Successfylly login as Admin");
            //operation here 
        }
        else if (validateEmpp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Successfylly login as " + txtUsername.Text);
            //operation here 
        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Incorrect password or username"); }
    }
```

Comment: The thing is i want to override the message if the username and password are correct ex: if admin logs in the message should say "logged in as admin" or when employee is logged in it says "Employee logged in" and so on..